# Rock that transfers image

Tags: materials, optical-properties

This is a question that has been bugging me for over 15 years!
In high school while studying elements our teacher showed us a clear white rock or element.

It was simply flat on both sides but when placed on a sheet of paper would transfer the letters from the page beneath it to the top surface of the rock.

I remember being amazed by this rock, but could not remember what it was.
Now I am working on a creative project and would love to see if I can incorporate the material in my design.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I used F'x answer as a starting point, and I found the mineral. It's called [Ulexite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulexite).

> The fibers of ulexite act as optical fibers, transmitting light along their lengths by internal reflection. When a piece of ulexite is cut with flat polished faces perpendicular to the orientation of the fibers, a good-quality specimen will display an image of whatever surface is adjacent to its other side (as shown in the photograph).

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure I understand what you want from the description above “transfer the letters”, but there is a typical high-school demonstration that I can think of that closely matches this description: that of **[birefringence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence)**.

[image]

[Calcite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcite) (featured above) was the first material with which this effect was observed, in 1669, and still an easily obtainable material for demonstrating it.

Comment: Very similar to this.  Perhaps my memor is bad.  What i remember is the image from the bottom sheet of paper looking like it was on top of the rock.  So if the rock is one inch thick and sitting on a newspaper, it would be as if the newspaper was on top of the mineral and not beneath.  I think the teacher said they were used for tv screens.   Dont remember it having the double effect.

Comment: FX thank you for your answer, helped me find exactly what i was looking for.